# useState is not working / got API error on my next/react project

Tags: next.js

### System

- Next.js 13 / React
- SendGrid

### Problems

- useState is not working
- Got an error message `API resolved without sending a response for /api/send, this may result in stalled requests.`

### Goal

- UseState is working
- Cleat the error

### Description

I'm Developping a contact-form page on my next project.

I want setIsPosted to True and display DOM

```
{isPosted && (
        <div className={styles.thanksMessage}>
          <p>Thanks for Contacting me</p>
        </div>
      )}
```

when submit button is clicked.

But not just working.
`console.log(result);` nothing shows up.

And also I got an error message of API.

How can I fix these problems?

### Scripts

form.js

```
import styles from "styles/form.module.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Form() {

  const [isPosted, setIsPosted] = useState(false);

  const post = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const res = await fetch('/api/send',{
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: event.target.name.value,
        company: event.target.company.value ? event.target.company.value : "",
        email: event.target.email.value,
        message: event.target.message.value,
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      method: "POST"
    })
    try {
      const result = await res.json();
      console.log(result);
      if (result){
        setIsPosted(true);
      }
    } catch(error){
      console.error(error)
    }
  };

  return (
    <form className={styles.items} onSubmit={post}>

      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 
      <input
        className={styles.submitButton}
        type="submit"
        value="submit"
      />
      {isPosted && (
        <div className={styles.thanksMessage}>
          <p>Thanks for Contacting me</p>
        </div>
      )}
      <style jsx>
        {`
          .is-deactive {
            border: 1px solid rgba(237, 238, 240, 0.5);
            color: var(--white);
            background: var(--accent);
          }
        `}
      </style>
    </form>

  );
}
```

send.js

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
    if(req.method === 'POST') {
      const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
      sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.EMAIL_API_KEY);

      const msg = {
        to: req.body.email,
        from: 'sample@example.com',
        subject: 'Thanks for Contacting me',
        text: 'Thanks for your contact. please wait for reply ' + req.body.message,
        html: 'Thanks for your contact. please wait for reply ' + req.body.message,
      };

      (async () => {
        try {
          await sgMail.send(msg);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
          if (error.response) {
            console.error(error.response.body)
          }
        }
      })();
    }

    res.status(200)

  }
```

Tried

`console.log(result);`

but nothing shows up.

Comment: You're not returning anything from your endpoint to the client-side.

Comment: If you are using next13 and the app folder make sure you are adding 'use client'; at the top of the file where you call the `useState`. I am not sure that is the issue since you would have gotten a different error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `const res = await fetch('/api/send',{...});` inside `try{ //here } catch{ }` because it is also a promise, and can fail

After: `console.log(res)` it just a debug to make sure.

Comment: I tried it, but situation is the same.
`console.log(res)` nothings shows up.

Comment: Then the error is in send.js you can `res.status(200).json({ status: true })`  if returns nothing, there is a problem using `@sendgrid/mail` I should debug in that part.

Comment: this code fixed literally everything!
`res.status(200).json({ status: true })`

thank you for your cooperation.